# How to configure mysql configuration for Ubuntu (RAM: 4GB CPU: 2VCPU SSD Disk: 80GB)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to improve my mysql performance. So I add more memory. But still slow in some part. Im most LEFT JOINs and UPDATE.

My database have 40GB of data.

My current mysql configuration is:

```
key_buffer              = 1024M
max_connections         = 3000
query_cache_size        = 256M
query_cache_limit       = 512M
thread_stack            = 32M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size =  512M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout= 150

table_cache = 2048
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
binlog_cache_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_concurrency = 8
thread_stack = 192K
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 2M
tmp_table_size = 64M
key_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
```

The question is. This is the best configuration ?

MY Serve is running: Digitalocean/Ubuntu16.04

RAM: 4GB
CPU: 2VCPU
SSD Disk: 80GB

Comment: the answers for this will be mainly opinion based, the best idea is to test yourself different onfigs and see which adapts better to your needs

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. There are seveal guides on the internet on how to configure mysql params according to available memory. Then, it is a bit vague, what means slow joins? Do you have set up proper indexes on your tables? FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291145/mysql-slow-on-join-any-way-to-speed-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section from the limited information posted in the original question,

```
thread_cache_size=50  # from 8 and monitor threads_created
thread_concurrency=16  # from 8 and monitor response time

# LEAD the following lines to allow DEFAULTS to work for you
# key_buffer=1024M  # lead with # to ignore, you have only 4G RAM
# max_connections=3000  # lead with # for default of 151, until more needed
# sort_buffer_size=8M
# read_buffer_size=2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
# join_buffer_size=8M
# thread_stack=32M
```

Take two minutes at www.mysqlcalculator.com to see how the above 
values unnecessarily increase your RAM footprint for each connection.
DEFAULTS frequently work very well for you.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, the best approach would profile some of the slowest queries and check why they are slow. Sometimes you are using a "where" (query criteria) without any index, sometimes you have too many indexes to be updated once you add/update values.

Please note that every field should be based over what you are running. A very dummy example. max_allowed_packet = 16M

You can make it smaller if you don't have batch queries or if you don't use Blobs. But if you store large blobs, you need this big enough to fit the bigger attachment you will store.