# Slow GroupBy query for filter results Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance, group-by

I am trying to filter search result on big rows tables. I tried both whereHas and WhereIn both queries are slow.

There are 3 tables, `places`, `categories`, `locations`.
Relation between places - categories and places - locations both are belongsToMany so there are 2 more pivot tables `place_category` and `place_location`.

places table contains about 100k+ rows

places - categories table contains about 650k+ rows, **place_category.place_id**  and **places.brand_id** column are **indexed**

places - locations table contains about 550k+ rows, **place_location.place_id** and **place_location.location_id** column are **indexed**

The queries I tried

```
Place::whereHas('locations', function($query) use($city) {
                            $query->where('locations.id', $city->id);
                        })
                        ->whereHas('categories', function($query){
                            $query->where('categories.id', 65);
                        })->groupBy('places.brand_id'->take(4)->get()
```

whereHas is the slowest, it takes about 3s

```
Place::whereIn('places.id', function($query) use($city) {
             $query->from('place_location')->select('place_location.place_id')->where('place_location.location_id', $city->id);
         })
         ->whereIn('places.id', function($query){
             $query->from('place_category')->select('place_category.place_id')->where('place_category.category_id', 65);
         })->groupBy('places.brand_id'->take(4)->get()
```

WhereIn takes about 2.6s

```
    Place::join('place_location', function ($join) use($city){
                  $join->on('place_location.place_id', '=', 'places.id')
                  ->where('place_location.location_id', '=',  $city->id);
               })
->join('place_category', function ($join){
               $join->on('place_category.place_id', '=', 'places.id')
                ->where('place_category.category_id', '=',  65);
            })->groupBy('places.brand_id')->take(4)->get();
```

Join takes about 1-2 s.

These queries are too slow

One of the problem I know causing the problem is the groupBy for last query with join, Any other way to get improve the query time?

Comment: Are you using indexes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291145/mysql-slow-on-join-any-way-to-speed-up

Comment: yes both pivot tables

Comment: places - categories table place_id and category_id column are indexed

places - locations table place_id and location_id column are indexed

All of the query time above are after the index and still slow

Comment: I think you should used query builder instead of eloquent.